# Jackrabbit on wildfly configured as War appliaction with jndiname

Tags: java, wildfly-8, jackrabbit, jca

I want a `Model 1` like deployment for JackRabbit on Wildfly along with a JNDI name to the resource ( java:/jcr/JcrRepository )
I have configured `jackrabbit-webapp-2.6.4.war` on `Wildlfy`.
I have configured my `resource.xml`, `bootstrap.properties` and the `jackrabbit-webapps/WEB-INF/web.xml` contain the correct paths to the `resource.xml` and the `bootstrap.properties`.

Also a different web-application accesses this jackrabbit repository and it needs to reference this jack rabbit resource through a JNDI name.

My question is where do I configure the JNDI name for Jackrabbit on Wildfly ?

If I were to configure it as a JCA adapter with `Model 2` like deployment, I could have configured it as a JCA subsystem in the `standalone-xml`, but in this case I want to follow a `Model 1` like deployment.

Any help from anybody ?

Comment: What happened to the stackoverflow users ? Have people stopped software development ?